# How to know which operators can be chained in Apache Flink

Tags: optimization, architecture, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm reading the doc of Apache Flink: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/runtime.html.

As the doc mentioned,

> For distributed execution, Flink chains operator subtasks together
>   into tasks. Each task is executed by one thread. Chaining operators
>   together into tasks is a useful optimization: it reduces the overhead
>   of thread-to-thread handover and buffering, and increases overall
>   throughput while decreasing latency.

So, as my understanding, knowing which operators can be chained is important. But how could we know about it? I mean, how can we know which operators can be chained and which operators can not?

For example, in the example of WordCount,

[image]

When we start to code, how could we know that `Source` and `map()` can be chained, that `map()` and `keyBy()/window()/apply()` can not be chained?

Comment: In addition to @david-anderson's answer above (which covers keyBy(), rebalance, and change in parallelism), note that [Async I/O operators] also lead to a break in the chain. [Async I/O operators]: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html#caveat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever two operators are connected by a FORWARDing data connection, they can be chained. In other words, a keyBy, rebalance, or change in parallelism (which is also a rebalance) forces network communication and makes operator chaining impossible.